# Joda Time's Period.getMillis returns inaccurate number

Tags: java, jodatime, period

I ran into a strange issue with JodaTime's Period class. I come to the point where I've instantiated a Period object, which is being printed as: PT8M19.966S, which clearly says 8 minutes and 19 seconds (this is correct at this point), and I call Period.toMillis. The result I get is some random number, such as 968, or 152, numbers that clearly are not what this method is supposed to return. So I wonder if it is some kind of bug, or misuse from my side.

Comment: Show us a reproducable example

Comment: ...this method doesn't exist?

Comment: sorry, I meant getMillis()...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean [`getMillis()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#getMillis%28%29)? The javadoc says it only returns the millisecond part of the period, not the period's duration in milliseconds.

Comment: I see... I read the docs but obviously I missed the 'part' thing. Since I don't see toStandartMillis I guess I have to use toStandardSeconds().getSeconds() * 1000. I will give it a try now...

Comment: The proper way to do this would be `Period.toStandardDuration().getMillis()`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman if the duration contains months, that will not work!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Louis above, you should convert `Period` to `Duration` first, and then get its milliseconds:

```
long millis = period.toStandardDuration().getMillis();
```

Main reason for that is that `ReadablePeriod` doesn't know exactly how many milliseconds it has inside, until you apply it to a calendar. For example, how many milliseconds are in one month?  We can't get an answer until this month is applied to a calendar.